# How to show rtmp live stream in web browser?

Tags: html, rtmp

I have setup a nginx server for live streaming, All is working fine and i can see live streaming VLC player.

I am trying to implement live streaming in web browser instead of VLC player but not getting any proper solution.

I saw many example for jw player but its not working. 
Anyone please advice what whould be best to see live stream in web browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible any more. It used to be possible with FASH, but flash is no longer supported. You must use a format that is supported like HLS or DASH

Comment: I have used HLS but it is only supporting safari browser. i want something that supports all browser

Comment: off topic, but there is still efforts of a stable [flash  browser](https://flash.pm/browser/)

Answer (score 0):

Cause I landed here late when trying to solve a similar issue, here is an answer I found useful.

One option may be using this project: [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server)

You might try using to proxy from rtmp to HLS. Then you would need to add HLS support to your browser (at this time non sarari browsers seem to need a JS fallback like [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js))

It the config yaml you probably want to add some section like this to bridge a single stream:

```
paths:
  hls:
    source: rtmp://example.com:1935/stream
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import time
import cv2 
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("live streaming **strong text**url")
    width = 1200
    height = 700
    dim = (width, height)
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            img = cv2.resize(img, dim, fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 
            frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else: 
            break
        

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

    
if __name__ ==('__main__'):
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 7600, app)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65407032/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.